# PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'ValueError: how to fix this error in Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I convert string to DateTime format I am getting this error.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'), DateType())

df_review_dt = df_review_fil.withColumn('datetime', func(col('date')))
```

> PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'ValueError: time data '2017-05-22' does not match > format '%m/%d/%Y'', from , line 5. Full traceback below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your date format was incorrect - it should be '%Y-%m-%d'. That said, the better way is to cast the column to date type directly.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_review_dt = df_review_fil.withColumn('datetime', F.col('date').cast('date'))
```